# Use HAProxy to ensure PrivateBin is truly for private usage

Tags: haproxy

I want to host my PrivateBin for my personal use. In other words, I want to make it unavailable for anyone to post on my PrivateBin from the internet. However, the generated posts should still be accessible from the internet.

PrivateBin cannot respond as is, but in my configuration, PrivateBin is behind HAProxy. To access the posts, PrivateBin uses the GET parameter "url" to transmit parameters and a private key.

My HAProxy version is 2.6.15 in OPNsense, listening on two interfaces for the public and private networks.

I have tried to create an ACL like this:

When a query goes to the private network (apps_interface) with the URL private.domain.tld, use the privatebin backend.

When a query goes to the public network (wan_interface) with the URL private.domain.tld and the parameter length is not equal to 0, use the privatebin backend.

For other queries, use the default site (which returns a 503 Service Unavailable).

Here is the truncated ACL in the WAN configuration:

Truncate ACL in WAN frontend:

```
    # logging options
    # ACL: path_not_match_root
    acl acl_6515e21ce0c558.11640870 urlp_len() eq 0
    # ACL: url_match_private_domain_tld
    acl acl_65148ebd13ad04.15527282 hdr(host) -i private.domain.tld

    # ACTION: use_backend_private_without_root_access
    use_backend private.domain.tld if !acl_6515e21ce0c558.11640870 acl_65148ebd13ad04.15527282
```

Example :

URL *https://private.domain.tld/?3e789210ae353a75#72h5XKJQ48wYa6oexF8sdmh4J1NxEtZcJBaZnpj3z3kU*

Must be available on public and private network

URL *https://private.domain.tld/*

Must be ONLY available on private network

However, with this configuration, nothing is being filtered.

Where is my configuration mistake?

Are there any other solutions available?

Best regards,

All configuration :

```
#
# Automatically generated configuration.
# Do not edit this file manually.
#

global
    uid                         80
    gid                         80
    chroot                      /var/haproxy
    daemon
    stats                       socket /var/run/haproxy.socket group proxy mode 775 level admin
    nbthread                    4
    hard-stop-after             60s
    no strict-limits
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param   2048
    spread-checks               2
    tune.bufsize                16384
    tune.lua.maxmem             0
    log                         /var/run/log local0 info
    lua-prepend-path            /tmp/haproxy/lua/?.lua
    ssl-default-bind-options prefer-client-ciphers ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256

defaults
    log     global
    option redispatch -1
    timeout client 30s
    timeout connect 30s
    timeout server 30s
    retries 3
    default-server init-addr last,libc

# Frontend: https_frontend_apps_interface (Incoming HTTPS connection only on APPS interface)
frontend https_frontend_apps_interface
    bind 10.90.0.254:443 name 10.90.0.254:443 ssl  crt-list /tmp/haproxy/ssl/64f47852586428.08925531.certlist 
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive
    default_backend 503
    option forwardfor

    # logging options
    # ACL: url_match_private_domain_tld
    acl acl_65148ebd13ad04.15527282 hdr(host) -i private.domain.tld

    # ACTION: use_backend_private_with_root_access
    use_backend private.domain.tld if acl_65148ebd13ad04.15527282

# Frontend: http_frontend (HTTP to HTTPS)
frontend http_frontend
    bind 10.90.0.254:80 name 10.90.0.254:80 
    bind 192.168.1.1:80 name 192.168.1.1:80 
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive

    # logging options
    # ACL: traffic_is_not_encrypted
    acl acl_64f4e61d399659.04737844 ssl_fc

    # ACTION: HTTP to HTTPS
    http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !acl_64f4e61d399659.04737844

# Frontend: https_frontend_wan_interface (Incoming HTTPS connection only on WAN interface)
frontend https_frontend_wan_interface
    bind 192.168.1.1:443 name 192.168.1.1:443 ssl  crt-list /tmp/haproxy/ssl/64f4eb8e55d356.37000700.certlist 
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive
    default_backend 503
    option forwardfor

    # logging options
    # ACL: path_not_match_root
    acl acl_6515e21ce0c558.11640870 urlp_len() eq 0
    # ACL: url_match_private_domain_tld
    acl acl_65148ebd13ad04.15527282 hdr(host) -i private.domain.tld

    # ACTION: use_backend_private_without_root_access
    use_backend private.domain.tld if !acl_6515e21ce0c558.11640870 acl_65148ebd13ad04.15527282

# Backend: 503 (503 error)
backend 503
    # HINT: no servers configured for this backend.
    # health checking is DISABLED
    mode http
    balance source
    # stickiness
    stick-table type ip size 50k expire 30m  
    stick on src
    http-reuse safe

# Backend: private.domain.tld (PrivateBin Apps)
backend private.domain.tld
    # health checking is DISABLED
    mode http
    balance source
    # stickiness
    stick-table type ip size 50k expire 30m  
    stick on src
    http-reuse safe
    server private 10.90.0.40:443 ssl verify none`
```